# Creating a list with file name, date created, date modified

Tags: windows, date, powershell, batch-file

What is the most sensible way to query for both dates. PowerShell or Windows Batch solutions are preferred.
I would like to have a list as described on the subject:

File name, date created, last modified

I know:
Dir has /t:[A,W,C] but couldn't find a way to display more than one date at a time.
For files has @fdate @ftime which only queries modified dates.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` piped into `Select-Object` would do the trick. This is well documented

Answer (score 6):

If PowerShell is acceptable:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Property Name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wmic datafile where (drive="C:" and path="\\somedir\\somesubdir\\") get Caption,CreationDate,LastModified
```

This is not a full script but just an example.Change drive and path to the dir you want list (mind of double slashes in the path).You also should care that the `WMIC` output is in unicode (unlike the cmd )
And WMIC is not available in XP home edition.

You can also use the build in jscript (every windows has it) and create a hybrid .bat/jscript (save/use the script as .bat) :

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /*JScript comment**

@echo off
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%~1"
exit /b 0

***************End of JScript comment**/

WScript.Echo("====starting===");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var folderC=args.Item(0);
if (WScript.Arguments.lengrh == 1 || args.Item(0)==""  ) folderC = ".";

WScript.Echo("Checking "+folderC);

function fileLIster(folderC){

    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var folder = fso.GetFolder(folderC);

    var fc = new Enumerator(folder.files);
    var s = "";
    for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
        s += fc.item() + " Created:[" + fc.item().DateCreated  + "] Modified:[" + fc.item().DateLastModified+"]" ;
        s += "\r\n";
    }
    WScript.Echo(s);

}
fileLIster(folderC);
```

This is a simple bat file that accepts a single argument for the directory you want to list files in and prints file names, creation date and date modified.

Answer (score 2):

Not very fast, but it works, and I think it is locale agnostic:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*) do for /f %%C in (
  'dir /tc "%%F"^|findstr "^[0-9]"'
) do for /f %%M in ("%%~tF") do echo "%%F", %%C, %%M
```

This is ***much*** faster, but I think it is dependent on the defined time format for your locale. You might have to change which tokens are captured in the first FOR /F loop:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,4*" %%A in (
  'dir /a-d /tc *^|findstr "^[0-9]"'
) do for /f %%M in ("%%~tC") do echo "%%C", %%A, %%M
```

My time format is `HH:MM AM`. If your time format is 24 hour format without AM/PM, then I think you need `"tokens=1,3*"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see like this in PowerShell:

```
 Directory: C:\project\CNN I\Maya                             

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name 
----                 -------------         ------ ---- 
-a----         1/11/2021  11:36 PM          32187 ocean wake foam.JPG                                                   
-a----          1/6/2021  12:28 AM         121100 ocean_clean.ma                                                        
-a----          1/4/2021   3:59 PM         122199 ocean_clean_1.ma
```

Please, try
`> get-childitem | sort-object -property name, creationtime, lastwritetime`

You don't see Date Created, but it actually is sorted by Name and Date Created (`creationtime`) and then Date Modified (`lastwritetime`). If you want to verify this, please try `> get-childitem | sort-object lastwritetime`. It will list the files by Date Modified.